# Using a trademarked word as part of another word

Tags: trademark

I have read many questions asking the opposite: splitting a trademark into multiple words.
Not sure if the scenario is the same.

Example: company named "FilterJedi" selling water filters, is this a trademark infringement because jedi is protected and is a famous term? even when the company is not using any logo or reference to StarWars and is not in the business of entertainment?

Comment: If there is no reference to "Star Wars", why use the Jedi name? "Jedi" was a word made up by George Lucas specifically for Star Wars, so it's difficult to imagine that you aren't implying *some* connection to the franchise...

Answer (score 3):

There are 95 Jedi trademarks on file. Tons of them are dead. The word "Jedi" itself is trademarked by Lucasarts (a subsidiary of Disney) under Registration Number 3794988, listed for print products and clothes, 2858244 for digital mediums,     2595365 for toys, 2823661 for entertainment services.

Now, most jedi marks are Lucasarts, but not all. [Serial 88625298](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=88625298) was "Jedi Ooolong", filed by Kombucha tea, which did get processed, filed and a denial/request for an amendment was sent back, and 6 months later the mark was canceled for non-answering. The request contained this line:

> Registration of the applied-for mark is refused because of a likelihood of confusion with the mark in U.S. Registration No. 5581531.  Trademark Act Section 2(d), 15 U.S.C. §1052(d); see TMEP §§1207.01 et seq.

Registration number 5581531 is/was "The Last Jedi" for juices, the rest of the document goes over why it is denied.

[Serial 88672347](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=88672347) is "Gediforce" for "Downloadable computer programs for data processing; downloadable computer programs designed to estimate costs and health impact of various gestational diabetes mellitus medical screening choices" - and this mark exists since about 2012 in Denmark and 2019 in the US, and granted this April. No conflicting marks.

[Serial 90150034](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=90150034) is "Chris Jedi" owned by a music label for music, clothes, and entertainment services - recently filed but not yet granted or even given to an examiner.

Comment: So it's possible to get approval, but also could take some years to know if it's approved or not? that means is a potential risk? Also I can see they are US patents, so if my company is not in USA then is OK?

Comment: @Enrique about half a year after registration you'll know. You can't *patent* a word.